# DNS server failure when forwarding

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

I run Bind 9 on a Ubuntu 12.04 server.
I want this server to be a sort of a "wrapper" over my default server, so that it will respond to "domain_name.My_TLD" itself and forward requests to any other request.

The server resides in a domain (Disconnected from the internet), so I configured it to

```
zone "company_domain."{
type forward;
forwarders { 1.2.3.4 }; #the DC's ip
};
```

When i query it about sommething.company_domain. it sends a query to the DC and gets a response, but it returns "server failure". What can cause that?

Cheers,
    Abraham

Comment: Is there anything useful in the `bind` logs?

Comment: It seems like it does log anything

Comment: Add a logging stanza to `named.conf` (see the docs for details).

Answer (score 1):

Is `1.2.3.4` the IP address of an authoritative server for `company_domain.`, or the IP address of another recursive server?

If it is the IP address of an authoritative server, then a forward zone is the wrong kind of zone to use: you need a stub zone.

```
zone "company_domain." {
    type stub;
    masters { 1.2.3.4 };
};
```

If it is the IP address of another recursive server, then you should be OK with a forward zone.

The difference between a forward zone and a stub zone is:

- forward: forward the DNS query as-is to the remote server, requesting recursion. The local server does not perform any kind of recursive resolution itself: it expects the remote server to do it. If recursion is not available from the remote server (it is an authoritative-only server, which is recommended best practice for authoritative nameservers) then the query will fail.
- stub: the local server performs recursive resolution of the query as usual, except it asks the authoritative servers given in the stub zone for the queries that fall inside the stub zone's domain, instead of finding the authoritative servers for that domain in the usual way. The local server does not request or expect recursion service when it forwards the query.